# Tikz matrix content is not layed out in tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to put a matrix into a tree layout.
The matrix itself appears at the right place, but its contained node is outside of the tree.

```
\tikz [
tree layout,
level sep = 1cm,
] {

\node[] (1) {1};

\node[
draw=green,
matrix,
] (2)
{ \node[draw=blue] (c1) {c1}; \\ };

\path (1) edge (2);
}
```

[image]

In reality, the tree consists of many matrices and each matrix is composed of many nodes.
This is just a minimal example showing the undesired behavior.

Comment: Please provide MWE (Minimal Working example) that we can test what you try so far.

Comment: A workaround might be to construct a subgraph instead of a matrix but recreating the matrix layout doesn't seem easy to do with the available graph drawing algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nodes inside a graph drawing scope (here the whole TikZ picture) gets “forwarded” to the graph drawing algorithm instead of placed directly.
This also happens to the nodes inside a matrix which will leave the matrix empty and `c1` as a normal graph drawing node.

I don't see a proper way to disable this forwarding, according to [the manual](https://tikz.dev/gd-usage-pgf#sec-29.2)

> [t]his is implemented on the lowest layer, namely by directly intercepting nodes freshly created using `\pgfnode`.

This appears to refer to the [*Deferred Node Positioning*](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#sec-106.2.3) which I can see being used in the code (and not by actually changing `\pgfnode` as I thought at first).

This deferred node positioning can be switched off by using

```
\pgfpositionnodelaterpath{\relax}
```

and this is what I install with `gd no matrix` in the code below at the start of every cell.

I've also added `\pgfgdgraphdrawingscopeactivefalse` though I haven't checked where this is needed.

Since the Graph Drawing library also intercepts the `edge` operation you probably can't use it inside a matrix or we need to disable this interception as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\tikzset{
  gd no matrix/.style={
    every cell/.append code=%
      \pgfgdgraphdrawingscopeactivefalse % maybe?
      \pgfpositionnodelater{\relax}%     % definitly
}}
\begin{document}
\tikz [
  tree layout,
  level sep = 1cm,
  gd no matrix
] {

\node[] (1) {1};

\node[
  draw=green,
  matrix
] (2){
  \node[draw=blue] (c1) {c1};
\\};

\path (1) edge (2);
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice idea. If I understand correctly, this allows many operations in the matrix node with the exception of "edge" - that is good. Does this approach also allow some transformations (like scaling) on the matrix node? My preliminary tests indicate that the matrix is built once and does not adhere to the insertion environment later.

Comment: @mafu The matrix node [doesn't allow the usual transformation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#\matrix): “Even though matrices are nodes, some options do not have the same effect as for normal nodes: 1. Rotations and scaling have no effect on a matrix as a whole (however, you can still transform the contents of the cells normally). Before the matrix is typeset, the rotational and scaling part of the transformation matrix is reset.” I don't know how Graph Drawing and Deferred Node Positioning would handle transformed node in the first place. Let alone matrix nodes.

Comment: Problematic will also be that there's `anchor` as well as a `matrix anchor` key which might be swapped for Graph Drawing, depending on how GD actually places these nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation